# Xpages doesn't work with fixpack 7 in Lotus Notes client

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

I have an Xpages application running in Lotus Notes Client. after some users have installed the last fixpack 7, the application opens, but the design (css, images) doesn't load [main screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXcBl.png). Lotus Notes client with FP5 and FP6 work perfectly. I compare the preferences options between FP5, FP6 and FP7 and i could find something different.

My co-worker has installed the FP7 and has got the following messages in the log when trying to open the app. it seems it is not recognizing the css

C:\notes\Data\IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT

11/8/16 1:16 PM: Exception Thrown com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.util.PageNotFoundException: Unknown resource /xsp/.ibmmodres/.css/newStyle2.css&newStyle1.css at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.websrv.servlets.DispatcherServlet.service(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.internal.ServletManager$ServletWrapper.service(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(Unknown Source) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.pvc.webhttpservice.BridgeServlet.service(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.pvc.internal.webcontainer.VirtualHost.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.http.HttpConnection.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

11/8/16 1:16 PM: Exception Thrown com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.util.PageNotFoundException: Unknown resource /xsp/.ibmmodres/.css/newStyle2.css&newStyle1.css at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.websrv.servlets.DispatcherServlet.service(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.internal.ServletManager$ServletWrapper.service(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(Unknown Source) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.pvc.webhttpservice.BridgeServlet.service(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.pvc.internal.webcontainer.VirtualHost.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.http.HttpConnection.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

11/8/16 1:17 PM: Exception Thrown com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.util.PageNotFoundException: Unknown resource /xsp/.ibmmodres/.css/newStyle2.css&newStyle1.css at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.websrv.servlets.DispatcherServlet.service(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.internal.ServletManager$ServletWrapper.service(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(Unknown Source) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.pvc.webhttpservice.BridgeServlet.service(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.pvc.internal.webcontainer.VirtualHost.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.http.HttpConnection.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

11/8/16 1:17 PM: Exception Thrown com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.util.PageNotFoundException: Unknown resource /xsp/.ibmmodres/.css/newStyle2.css&newStyle1.css at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.websrv.servlets.DispatcherServlet.service(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.internal.ServletManager$ServletWrapper.service(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(Unknown Source) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.pvc.webhttpservice.BridgeServlet.service(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.pvc.internal.webcontainer.VirtualHost.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.http.HttpConnection.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

11/8/16 2:36 PM: Exception Thrown com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.util.PageNotFoundException: Unknown resource /xsp/.ibmmodres/.css/newStyle2.css&newStyle1.css at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.websrv.servlets.DispatcherServlet.service(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.internal.ServletManager$ServletWrapper.service(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(Unknown Source) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.pvc.webhttpservice.BridgeServlet.service(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.pvc.internal.webcontainer.VirtualHost.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.http.HttpConnection.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

11/8/16 2:36 PM: Exception Thrown com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.util.PageNotFoundException: Unknown resource /xsp/.ibmmodres/.css/newStyle2.css&newStyle1.css at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.websrv.servlets.DispatcherServlet.service(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.internal.ServletManager$ServletWrapper.service(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(Unknown Source) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.pvc.webhttpservice.BridgeServlet.service(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.pvc.internal.webcontainer.VirtualHost.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.http.HttpConnection.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

11/8/16 2:40 PM: Exception Thrown com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.util.PageNotFoundException: Unknown resource /xsp/.ibmmodres/.css/newStyle2.css&newStyle1.css at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.websrv.servlets.DispatcherServlet.service(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.internal.ServletManager$ServletWrapper.service(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(Unknown Source) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.pvc.webhttpservice.BridgeServlet.service(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.pvc.internal.webcontainer.VirtualHost.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.http.HttpConnection.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

11/8/16 2:40 PM: Exception Thrown com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.util.PageNotFoundException: Unknown resource /xsp/.ibmmodres/.css/newStyle2.css&newStyle1.css at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.websrv.servlets.DispatcherServlet.service(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.internal.ServletManager$ServletWrapper.service(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(Unknown Source) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.pvc.webhttpservice.BridgeServlet.service(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.pvc.internal.webcontainer.VirtualHost.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.http.HttpConnection.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

After make a test we found some differents. When we open the app in the LN client and check the view page resources

[Differents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FD157.png)

for some reason is duplicating the xsp word in the path when you attach more than 1 file in the resource option of the xpages element. please your help

Comment: Do you get any client side errors? There are some issues in FP7 but AFAIK no problems with XPages related stuff. Please check the error console in the client window.

Comment: I added a screen of the log viewer, it seems that it is not recognizing the css from the resources

Answer (score 2):

Are you relying on any open source plugins, e.g. latest version of Extension Library?

Some fix pack installs have been known to delete all custom plugins, so using a Bootstrap theme would not work, because the core Extension Library doesn't include it.

Comment: I don't use theme in the app. "Application Theme: Platform default" and in extension library section, the options are unchecked :(

Comment: I found the solution. For some reason it is not recognizing more than 2 css files or 2 js files in each element when you run the tool in Lotus notes client. I had to join them in one file. I mean 1 css and 1 js by xpages element.

Comment: Do you know if you had "Use runtime optimized JavaScript and CSS resources" ticked? I wonder if that was causing an issue with XPiNC when trying to create a merged link. If so, deselecting that may have been an alternate solution to the problem.

Comment: Hello @PaulStephen, Sorry for the delay to answer. I didn't know about that option. Looking for in internet the option should be in application properties > xpages tab > performance section but it isn't. I don't know if it is because i have the last FP7 installed.

Comment: That was the location prior to Notes 9. Most XPages settings have now been moved to Application Configuration > Xsp Properties, and that should be your default starting place to check for XPages settings for the NSF. This one is on the Persistence tab.

Comment: I could find the option. I did the test in a previous template. by default is checked, i unchecked and worked. thank you so much for that tip :)